# Error:(14) No resource identifier found for attribute 'fillType' in package

Tags: android, path, android-vectordrawable

When I use `vectorDrawable` instead of `png/jpeg`, I use `fillType` in `path`.

I receive the following error:

> "Error:(14) No resource identifier found for attribute 'fillType' in package 'android'"

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I assume not as long as there is not more code to have a look at... For me this is hard to follow with no code attached! Additionally you might want to add tags like [tag:android] for example to bring the experts for that tag here!